# How to store a featureclass's Domain, Resolution and Tolerance when migrating to PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, esri-geodatabase, precision, tolerance

I'd like to copy a featureclass from an Esri Geodatabase into PostGIS and have it retain the Domain, XY Resolution and XY Tolerance values associated with it.

I don't see a table in PostGIS (or in the Geopackage spec, for that matter) where I can store this info.

Is there some "best practice" describing how to manage this information in PostGIS?

Comment: Those properties live in enterprise geodatabase metadata tables. While even Query Layers still have these properties, they are not present at the PostGIS `geometry`/`geography` data tier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGIS doesn't implement those concepts explicitly, and thus does not store metadata about them.  If you need to retain them you will have to maintain your own metadata table.

Comment: Not quite true. If the database is enterprise geodatabase enabled, those properties live on in the geodatabase metadata, whether they are used for database-level queries or not.